# Sql Server ContainsTable return zero result when try to select top records

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, containstable

We have implemented `ContainsTable` in SQL Server. Problem is when we run the query as following

```
select DATAFILENAME 
from TableName
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (TableName, BOOLEANTEXT, '("xxxx" )  ') AS KEY_TBL ON DATAFILENAME = KEY_TBL.[KEY]  and CASETYPE like '%xxxx%'
```

This will return about 1200 records.

But I just want to select top 1000, here is the query as following

```
select DATAFILENAME 
from TableName
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (TableName, BOOLEANTEXT, '("xxxx",*1000* )  ') AS KEY_TBL ON DATAFILENAME = KEY_TBL.[KEY]  and CASETYPE like '%xxxx%'**
```

This query will return zero records.

I have rebuild full text index, change tracking to auto. But still showing zero result.

Please advice if I am missing some points. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with just using Limit 1000? or Select Top 1000?

Comment: actully i want to limit the result to first 1000. with containstable i add Amount (1000) of recored i want to call, but it is always return Zero, when i remove the amount(1000) from containstable ,it shows result , so im really do not understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two queries are:

```
select DATAFILENAME
from TableName INNER JOIN
      CONTAINSTABLE(TableName, BOOLEANTEXT, '("xxxx" ) ')AS KEY_TBL
      ON DATAFILENAME = KEY_TBL.[KEY] and CASETYPE like '%xxxx%'
```

and:

```
select DATAFILENAME
from TableName INNER JOIN
      CONTAINSTABLE(TableName, BOOLEANTEXT, '("xxxx" ) ', 1000)AS KEY_TBL
      ON DATAFILENAME = KEY_TBL.[KEY] and CASETYPE like '%xxxx%'
```

The first returns 1,200 records and the second no records.

Conclusion:  The first 1,000 rows returned by `CONTAINSTABLE` have no match in `TableName` using the conditions specified.

If you want only 1,000 rows, use `top 1000`:

```
select top 1000 DATAFILENAME
from TableName INNER JOIN
      CONTAINSTABLE(TableName, BOOLEANTEXT, '("xxxx" ) ')AS KEY_TBL
      ON DATAFILENAME = KEY_TBL.[KEY] and CASETYPE like '%xxxx%'
order by KEY_TBL.rank desc;
```

Note the `order by KEY_TBL.rank`, so the best matching rows will be returned first.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I agree with your logic but im trying to get the result within containstable.by following your query,result will contain all records and then select top 1000. My target is to get 1000 records from containstable directly. that will reduce time of extracting result. Any other suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can get this by including `top_n_by_rank` in your query:

```
select DATAFILENAME 
from TableName
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE (TableName, BOOLEANTEXT, '("xxxx" )  ', 1000) AS KEY_TBL 
    ON DATAFILENAME = KEY_TBL.[KEY]  
    and CASETYPE like '%xxxx%'
```

The `1000` term will limit the `CONTAINSTABLE` results.

n.b. If top_n_by_rank is combined with other parameters, the query could return fewer rows than the number of rows that actually match all the predicates. top_n_by_rank allows you to increase query performance by recalling only the most relevant hits. So, it could return less than 1000 records depending on the relevancy of the results

Comment: Beware! It's not exactly what it does as Microsoft says:
top_n_by_rank
Specifies that only the n highest ranked matches, in descending order, are returned. Applies only when an integer value, n, is specified. If top_n_by_rank is combined with other parameters, the query could return fewer rows than the number of rows that actually match all the predicates. top_n_by_rank allows you to increase query performance by recalling only the most relevant hits.

So, it could return less than 1000 records depending on the relevancy of the results

Comment: @Stéphan That is a very good point.  I've edited my answer to reflect that potential gotcha.